Gratis Serial Monitor for Windows
The Serial Monitor of Arduino IDE 2.x is seriously broken. I need a replacement, which

works on Windows 10 64 Bit
is completely gratis, since I use it with kids
displays Emojis (which was broken in Arduino IDE as well some time ago)
allows copying long text (at least longer than what's currently on the screen; a bug in Arduino IDE 2.x)
the COM port can be selected from a list of COM ports
the program indicates which COM port is a USB COM port (because they know it's connected via USB)
the baud rate can be selected from a drop-down list, with values up to 2000000 baud
has an autoscroll feature, scrolling down to the bottom automatically, and that feature can be turned off
has a button to clear the output window
can display the timestamps of arrived data
can receive data and send data

I have tried the following and I'm really shocked how bad Serial Monitors still are these days:

all products given as answers here

PortMon does not work with 64 bit
Aggsoft advanced serial data logger is not free
Eltima RS232 Data Logger is not free
HiTerminalLogger does not run on my PC. It always exits with an error message.


products given as answers here

RealTerm is too technical. The UI is too hard to use for kids.
No, I won't code something myself using Python
Termite has a maximum baud rate of 230400 and can't display time stamps.
comDebug has too many unrelated features and displays COM ports which are actually not connected.




try writing your own using Processing
